# Convert "20100426T000000Z" timestamp to datetime in .netcore

Tags: c#, .net-core

```
string s = "20100426T000000Z";
 DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Tried this getting invalid string format issue. Can somebody help me in this.

Comment: The format specifier needs to match the input string - change to `"yyyyMMddTHHmmssz"`

Comment: `20100426T000000Z` is not in the format `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm` (which would see require the value of `s` to be this: `04/26/2010 00:00`).

Comment: Re your comment: z != Z

Comment: thankyou  @MathiasR.Jessen. Issue got fixed

Answer (score 1):

This should do it :

```
    string s = "20100426T000000Z";
    DateTime theDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```